# How do i count how many times a value is present in power bi?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

How can I get the count of how many times a specific row appears like in this example the value Good appears 2 times.

| Col1 |
| --- |
| Bad |
| Okay |
| Good |
| Bad |
| Good |
| Okay |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a specific measure that doesn't require the filter pane,

```
CountGood = CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Table1[Col1] ), Table1[Col1] = "Good" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new measure:

```
Row count = COUNTROWS ( 'Table' )
```

Create a new table visual, drag in `Col1` and the `Row count` measure to the visual.

You can also drag `Col1` into the table visual twice, and change the aggregation on one of the columns to Count:

[image: Demo]